# como leer los canales del TCA9548A

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Hace poco adquirí un `multiplexor TCA9548A` para conectar un par de sensores de dirección fija, pero hasta ahora no e podido saber como leer los diferentes canales de este, por cierto lo tengo conectado a un `raspberry`.

Encontré este código que aparentemente funciona pero no se que hace ni para que sirve.

Anexo dicho código:

```
import smbus

class multiplex:

    def __init__(self, bus):
        self.bus = smbus.SMBus(bus)

    def channel(self, address=0x70,channel=0):  # values 0-3 indictae the channel, anything else (eg -1) turns off all channels

        if   (channel==0): action = 0x04
        elif (channel==1): action = 0x05
        elif (channel==2): action = 0x06
        elif (channel==3): action = 0x07
        else : action = 0x00

        self.bus.write_byte_data(address,0x04,action)  #0x04 is the register for switching channels 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    bus=1       # 0 for rev1 boards etc.
    address=0x70

    plexer = multiplex(bus)
    plexer.channel(address,3)

    print "Now run i2cdetect"
```